# Powershell Rename Multiple Files with LastWriteTime Prefix

Tags: powershell

I am trying to put together a Powershell script that will:

-Search recursively from a root directory
-Exclude files with existing "yyyyMMdd " file name prefix
-Rename the files not excluded above with ""yyyyMMdd " file name prefix based on their specific LastWriteTime

Note: ideally, this script should include all file type extensions

I have tried myself, but it would seem to be above my head, as my attempts are not going well.

Thanks, in advance.

http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-stampme.html

```
#StampMe.ps1
param( [string] $fileName)

# Check the file exists
if (-not(Test-Path $fileName)) {break}

# Display the original name
"Original filename: $fileName"

$fileObj = get-item $fileName

# Get the date
$DateStamp = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d@%H-%M-%S"

$extOnly = $fileObj.extension

if ($extOnly.length -eq 0) {
   $nameOnly = $fileObj.Name
   rename-item "$fileObj" "$nameOnly-$DateStamp"
   }
else {
   $nameOnly = $fileObj.Name.Replace( $fileObj.Extension,'')
   rename-item "$fileName" "$nameOnly-$DateStamp$extOnly"
   }

# Display the new name
"New filename: $nameOnly-$DateStamp$extOnly"
```

I am hoping to change the line:

```
$DateStamp = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d@%H-%M-%S"
```

To be LastWriteTime instead of get-date, but I have no idea how to make this happen.

This code (from another Super User question):

```
Get-ChildItem "Test.pdf" | Rename-Item -newname {$_.LastWriteTime.toString("yyyyMMdd") + " Test.pdf"}
```

...successfully renames a single file, but I can't seem to integrate this into the larger script.

---

With regards to running the above recursively, I have tried this (also from http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-stampme.html):

```
foreach ($file in get-ChildItem *.* -recurse) { ./StampMe.ps1 $file.name }
```

Which succeeds to apply the PS script to files in the root directory, but fails to apply to any files in the sub-folder tree that propagates from the root directory.

Comment: "my attempts are not going well" - Please show us your code snippets anyway. Remember, we are not a script writing service

Comment: I don't have any original code snippets, just code I have found searching on the internet. I have edited the main question to include what I have discovered, so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script should do exactly what you want

> - Search recursively from a root directory
> - Exclude files with existing "yyyyMMdd " file name prefix
> - Rename the files not excluded above with ""yyyyMMdd " file name prefix based on their specific LastWriteTime

Warning: You should test this script first because renaming could be dangerous. Remove the `#` in front of `Rename-Item`after you have verified that only intentional files will be renamed.

#### Long version

```
$folder = "C:\somefolder"
$files = get-childitem -path $folder -recurse | where { -not $_.PSIsContainer }
[datetime]$dirDate = New-Object DateTime

foreach ($file In $files) {

    $strDate = $file.Name.substring(0,8)

    if (-Not [DateTime]::TryParseExact($strDate, "yyyyMMdd", 
        [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, 
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref]$dirDate)) {

        $newName = $file.lastwritetime.tostring("yyyyMMdd ") + $file.name
        echo $newName
        #Rename-Item -path $file.Fullname -newname $newName
    }   
}
```

#### Short version

```
[datetime]$dirDate = New-Object DateTime

dir "C:\somefolder" -r | ? { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | % {          

    if ( ! [DateTime]::TryParseExact($_.Name.substring(0,8), "yyyyMMdd", 
        [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, 
        [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref]$dirDate)) {

        $newName = $_.lastwritetime.tostring("yyyyMMdd ") + $_.name
        echo $newName
        #Ren $_.Fullname $newName
    }
}
```

#### Used stackoverflow answers

- [`[DateTime]::TryParseExact`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393630/935614) to test if the first 8 characters can be a valid date
- [`$_.lastwritetime.tostring("yyyyMMdd ")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334326/935614) to format the *lastwrite* stamp

Comment: This worked perfectly. Your effort is sincerely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan Please remember to accept an answer if you found it helpful. You can click the big checkbox left of an answer to accept it.

Comment: @Rik. Thanks for the tip. I did try to vote the answer up but was prevented by lack of "reputation".

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar - eg rename files based on lastwritetime. Here's the powershell that does that:

- Renames any/all files in current directory
- Preserves file extensions
- Names in yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss format (24hr)

`ls | % { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ($_.extension)) }`